# CSS & jQuery: Element moving Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want a banner to move down into the site from the top after it's loaded. The element moving in from the top should push the rest of the page down to get more attention. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```css
.hinweis-wrapper {
  background: #00abe8;
 padding: 25px;
}

.hinweis {
 color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {margin: 0}

.rest-of-website {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<div class="hinweis-wrapper">
  <div class="hinweis">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rest-of-website">
</div>
```

I want the black element to move down when the blue element comes in. I tried to use `transform: translateY(...)` bound to a jQuery `(document).ready(function()` but the black element remains where it is while the blue element is animated.

Comment: _"I tried to use 'transform: translateY(...)' bound to a jQuery '(document).ready(function()'"_ - Why is this not part of your "question"? -> [mcve]

Comment: I asked a "question" and thanked in advance, but it seems to have disappeared. Kindness does not seem to be an effective part of communication: /

Comment: @flip It is explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/204841 and in this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/1288408

Comment: @ModusTollens Thank you! I'll keep that in mind for the next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the height of the banner/header via jQuery, apply that value times -1 as a negative `margin-top` to the `.hinweis-wrapper` and animate that to 0 via jQuery.

To avoid that element to first show for a moment (before the negative margin is applied via jQuery), you can apply `display: none` to it in the css and change that in the jQuery function on document load before everything else.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = $(".hinweis-wrapper").outerHeight() * -1;
  $(".hinweis-wrapper").css({display: 'block', marginTop: offset}).animate({
    marginTop: '0px'
  }, 1000);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.hinweis-wrapper {
  background: #00abe8;
  padding: 25px; 
  display: none;
}

.hinweis {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  margin: 0
}

.rest-of-website {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hinweis-wrapper">
  <div class="hinweis">
    <p>This is the header, which has dynamic height</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rest-of-website">
  <p>This is the Website Content</p>
  <p>(dynamic content)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot to say that the blue banner is dynamic content with no fixed height. It is a banner for important messages like company opening hours on holidays etc.

The black item should represent the complete rest of the page. It is not really a single item.

Comment: updated answer after comment: well, then you can get  the height of that banner with jQuery, first apply it as a negative margin and then animate it to zero. The contents of the black are don't have any impact on that, it can contain whatever you want.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Johannes! That should do it!

Comment: You are welcome! Note: I edited the jQuery code once more to avoid unneccessary repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Jquery version, which moves the black element down after page loads. For animating it you could use `.slideDown(duration, functionOnEnd())`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
function ready() {
  $('.rest-of-website').css('margin-top', $('.hinweis-wrapper').prop("margin-top"));
}
```

```css
.hinweis-wrapper {
  background: #00abe8;
 padding: 25px;
}

.hinweis {
 color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {margin: 0}

.rest-of-website {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hinweis-wrapper">
  <div class="hinweis">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="rest-of-website">
</div>
```

Comment: Johannes way worked a bit easier, but thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it